# Is it possible to read a secret or closed Facebook group feed with the API?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

The [Facebook API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed) doesn't clearly state if it's possible to read a secret or closed group feed that the user is **a member of**, and I didn't succeed no matter the permissions asked. It works with owned groups though (and the *user_managed_groups* permission).

> #### Permissions
>
> - Any valid access token for a public group (i.e. the group's privacy
>   setting is OPEN).
> - A user access token for a member of the group.
> - The user_managed_groups permission can be used to read the group content
>   for a group in which the user is an admin. This permission also allows
>   the app to post as the user in the group if the app is also granted
>   the publish_actions permission.
> - An app access token can read posts it published in app and game groups that belong to it.

**Does anybody succeeded reading a secret or closed Facebook group feed with the API?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The user_managed_groups permission can be used to read the group content for a group in which the user is an admin

As long as the user is admin, it should work. Afaik it does not work if you are just a member.

Comment: Just to confirm, I tried to fetch API data from a group secret & closed I'm a member of, it doesn't work. Only works when the user owns the group.

Comment: exactly. i assume one reason is that it would be easy to put stuff from a secret group online somewhere else as member - while other members don´t know about it. it´s called secret for a reason.